# Node, Typescript ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND

Tags: node.js, typescript

I've tried to set up a base project with Node and TypeScript.

I cannot figure out what I've missed from my settings or what might be incorrect, I've experimented with different options for tsconfig/nodemon but nothing seems to work properly, and cannot successfully to compile the project.

Error:

```
/home/temp/ts-test/node_modules/ts-node/dist-raw/node-esm-resolve-implementation.js:383
    throw new ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND(
          ^
CustomError: Cannot find module '/home//temp/ts-test/lib/core/api' imported from /home/temp/ts-test/index.ts
    at finalizeResolution (/home/temp/ts-test/node_modules/ts-node/dist-raw/node-esm-resolve-implementation.js:383:11)
    at moduleResolve (/home/temp/ts-test/node_modules/ts-node/dist-raw/node-esm-resolve-implementation.js:818:10)
    at Object.defaultResolve (/home/temp/ts-test/node_modules/ts-node/dist-raw/node-esm-resolve-implementation.js:929:11)
    at /home/temp/ts-test/node_modules/ts-node/src/esm.ts:228:33
    at entrypointFallback (/home/temp/ts-test/node_modules/ts-node/src/esm.ts:179:34)
    at resolve (/home/temp/ts-test/node_modules/ts-node/src/esm.ts:227:12)
    at ESMLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:422:30)
    at ESMLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:222:40)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:76:40)
    at link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:75:36)
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "ts-test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.ts",
  "directories": {
    "lib": "lib"
  },
  "type": "module",
  "dependencies": {
    "dotenv": "^16.0.0",
    "node-fetch": "^3.2.3",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.15",
    "ts-node": "^10.7.0",
    "typescript": "^4.6.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^17.0.23",
    "@types/node-fetch": "^2.6.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon -w src index.ts"
  },
}
```

nodemon.json

```
{
    "execMap": {
        "ts": "NODE_ENV=development  NODE_OPTIONS='--loader ts-node/esm' ts-node -T"
    },
    "watch": [
        "./lib"
    ],
    "ext": "ts,js,json,yaml,yml"
}
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "esnext",
        "target": "es6",
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "lib": [
            "es6",
            "dom"
        ],
    },
    "include": [
        "lib/**/*",
    ]
}
```

index.ts

```
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';
import { Api} from './lib/core/api';
import { HttpClient } from './lib/core/request';

dotenv.config();
const baseUrl = 'https://example.com';

const httpClient = new HttpClient(baseUrl, process.env.TOKEN);
```

Comment: Isn't `Cannot find module '/home//temp/ts-test/lib/core/api' imported from /home/temp/ts-test/index.ts` pretty clear?

Comment: it is clear, the module exists, if I will change nodemon `execMap` config or tsconifg option it will give another error like .ts unknown extension or export is not defined

Comment: Please ask one specific question at a time. Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see your problem, when using ESM `index.js` is not assumed by default when you specify a directory. You have to specify the filename with the extension `mjs`.

If you don't want to use the `mjs` extension, modify your package.json to add `"type": "module"`.

> You don't have to add an extension to libraries unless you import from a specific path in the library.

```
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';
import { Api} from './lib/core/api/index.js';
import { HttpClient } from './lib/core/request.js';

dotenv.config();

const baseUrl = 'https://example.com';

const httpClient = new HttpClient(baseUrl, process.env.TOKEN);
```

In your `nodemon.json` config, you can simplify the `execMap.ts` script:

```json
{
  "watch": ["lib"],
  "execMap": {
    "ts": "node --loader ts-node/esm"
  },
  "watch": ["lib"],
  "ext": "ts"
}
```